# Ligatures not shown

Tags: xetex, ligatures, hoefler

Even though there's a number of topics on here concerning the subject, it still doesn't work here.

An example like:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec,graphicx,xltxtra}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Ligatures={Common,Rare,Historic},Alternate=1]{Hoefler Text}

\begin{document}

\Huge
\noindent
Que dictes vous de mon appel,\\
Garnier? Fis je sens ou folie?\\
Toute beste garde sa pel\\
Qui la contraint, efforce ou lie\\
S'elle peut, elle se deslie

fire flower fjörd\\

fi fl

ﬁ ﬂ

\end{document}
```

Doesn't work. The last line DOES show ligatures, but any other line doesn't.
It also says this in the logs:

```
Requested font "Hoefler Text" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/Windows/Fonts/HoeflerText-Roman.otf
Requested font "Hoefler Text/ICU" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/Windows/Fonts/HoeflerText-Roman.otf

 fontspec warning: OpenType feature 'Ligatures=Common' (+liga) not available
(fontspec)  for font 'Hoefler Text',
(fontspec)  with script 'Latin', and language 'Default'.

 fontspec warning: OpenType feature 'Ligatures=Rare' (+dlig) not available
(fontspec)  for font 'Hoefler Text',
(fontspec)  with script 'Latin', and language 'Default'.

 fontspec warning: OpenType feature 'Ligatures=Historic' (+hlig) not available
(fontspec)  for font 'Hoefler Text',
(fontspec)  with script 'Latin', and language 'Default'.

 fontspec warning: OpenType feature 'Alternate=1' (+salt=1) not available
(fontspec)  for font 'Hoefler Text',
(fontspec)  with script 'Latin', and language 'Default'.
```

Why does it simply not work? I've tried many alternatives people mentioned, but it never gets full with ornaments and nice jolly shapes.

I'm using MiKTeX, compiling with XeLaTeX.

Secondly, I'm not sure how the naming system for fonts works. Can I check which file is called what in LaTeX? Maybe I need Hoefler Text, instead of HoeflerText-Roman, or something...

Comment: this has worked for me on OS X, where the full suite of hofler text fonts are availble... looks like you just don't have the full font with ligatures available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the `.otf` files you use, don’t actually have all those ligatures available. That’s what the error messages say. The last line uses the hardcoded ligatures available in some legacy encodings. Have you tried using some other `.otf` file which might have advanced ligatures included?

Comment: Hmm yes. Minion Pro does seem to have ligatures. I must say the HoeflerText file is somewhat small, 50kB, while MinionPro is 2.5MB.

Sigh, that's a pity :(